# Can you use navigation sub-properties in foreign keys using EF 4.1 fluent API?

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, fluent-interface

Let's use a simple example:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Pay> Pays { get; set; }
}

public class Pay
{
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; }
}
```

Is there any way to use the fluent API to create a Pays table with a primary key on  `Employee_EmployeeID, Year` (using EF4.1 column conventions)?

I don't want to use data annotations but I tried this anyway:

```
public class Pay
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; }
}
```

All that got me was a primary key on `Year` and a foreign key on `Employee_EmployeeID` though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be only possible if you also add FK property to your `Pay`:

```
public class Pay
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can map it with fluent-api:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Pay>()
            .HasKey(p => new 
                {
                    p.EmployeeId,
                    p.Year
                });
```

You need employee's FK as a property if you want to make it part of PK.